# Upload files using retrofit2 - file was being uploaded but on "onFailure" response

Tags: android, file, upload, retrofit2

I need to upload an image as a file, already tried different solutions from the stack but I still stuck. Anyone can explain to me what I am doing wrong?

**UPLOAD FUNCTION**

```
private void EnviarFotos(){
    iGeoPBService geoPBService = GeoPBService.getInstance().usarServico();
    List<Foto> listaFotos = bancoDadosController.syncFotos();
    for (final Foto foto : listaFotos){
        String numObra = foto.getNumeroObra();
        String idAcomp = foto.getIdAcompanhamento();
        String idMedicao = foto.getIdMedicao();
        String imagem = foto.getImagem();
        final File file = FileFoto(imagem);
        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),file);
        MultipartBody.Part multipartBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file",foto.getNomeFoto(),requestFile);
        if (idAcomp.equals("N/A")){
            Call<String> envioMed = geoPBService.uploadFotoMedicao(idJurisdicionado,numObra,idMedicao,multipartBody);
            envioMed.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()){
                        bancoDadosController.atualizaStatusSyncFoto(foto.getNomeFoto());
                        AttInfos();
                        Log.d("TESTE","FOTO ENVIADA COM SUCESSO!!!");
                        file.delete();
                    }else {
                        Log.d("TESTE","msg :"+ response.message());
                        Log.d("TESTE","errorBody :"+ response.errorBody().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),response.message(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("TESTE","DEU MERDA!!!");
                    Log.d("TESTE","throw :"+ t.getMessage());
                    Log.d("TESTE","cause :"+ t.getCause());
                    Log.d("TESTE","lmsg :"+ t.getLocalizedMessage());
                    Log.d("TESTE","Stack :"+ t.getStackTrace().toString());

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

        }else {
            Call<String> envioAcomp = geoPBService.uploadFotoAcompanhamento(idJurisdicionado,numObra,idAcomp,multipartBody);
            envioAcomp.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                    AttInfos();
                    Log.d("TESTE","FOTO ENVIADA COM SUCESSO!!!");
                    file.delete();

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("TESTE","DEU MERDA!!!");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

**INTERFACE**

```
public interface iGeoPBService {

@Multipart
@POST("obras/uploadFotoMedicao/{jurisdicionado}/{numObra}/{idMedicao}")
Call<String> uploadFotoMedicao(@Path("jurisdicionado") String idJurisdicionado,@Path("numObra")String numObra,@Path("idMedicao") String idMedicao, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);

@Multipart
@POST("obras/uploadFotoAcompanhamento/{jurisdicionado}/{numObra}/{idAcompanhamento}")
Call<String> uploadFotoAcompanhamento(@Path("jurisdicionado") String idJurisdicionado, @Path("numObra")String numObra, @Path("idAcompanhamento") String idAcompanhamento, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

}

My code already has some changes based on other answers a similar question about upload files with retrofit2 but after executing my code always fall on "onFailure"

**Logcat show this:**

```
07-13 14:14:44.035 8937-8937/despesalegal.tce.pb.gov.br.despesalegal D/TESTE: 
throw :Expected value at line 1 column 1 path $
07-13 14:14:44.035 8937-8937/despesalegal.tce.pb.gov.br.despesalegal D/TESTE: 
cause :null
07-13 14:14:44.035 8937-8937/despesalegal.tce.pb.gov.br.despesalegal D/TESTE: 
localized msg :Expected value at line 1 column 1 path $
07-13 14:14:44.035 8937-8937/despesalegal.tce.pb.gov.br.despesalegal D/TESTE: 
Stacktrace :[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@b4b765b
```

**My file was being uploaded to the server but on retrofit "onFailure" response method**

What I'm doing wrong? Actually, the problem can be on the server side?

**[EDIT]**

I changed some things on my code and now I'm getting the "onResponse" correctly.

**SERVICE CLASS**

```
private void buildRetrofit(String baseUrl) {

    *OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
    clientBuilder.addInterceptor(logging);
    clientBuilder.retryOnConnectionFailure(false);
    clientBuilder.followRedirects(true);
    OkHttpClient client = clientBuilder.retryOnConnectionFailure(true).build();*

    *Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();*

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            *.client(client)*
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    this.requestsGeo = retrofit.create(iGeoPBService.class);
}
```

**INTERFACE**

```
@Multipart
@POST("obras/uploadFotoMedicao/{jurisdicionado}/{numObra}/{idMedicao}")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadFotoMedicao(@Path("jurisdicionado") String idJurisdicionado, @Path("numObra")String numObra, @Path("idMedicao") String idMedicao, @Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("name") RequestBody name);

@Multipart
@POST("obras/uploadFotoAcompanhamento/{jurisdicionado}/{numObra}/{idAcompanhamento}")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadFotoAcompanhamento(@Path("jurisdicionado") String idJurisdicionado, @Path("numObra")String numObra, @Path("idAcompanhamento") String idAcompanhamento,@Part MultipartBody.Part body,@Part("name") RequestBody name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your RequestBody to this:

```
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
```

Your MediaType sent were wrong...

Comment: Actually, the file is being uploaded to my server but the upload is occurring on "onFailure" retrofit response. I can't understand this behavior.

Comment: Try to change the type of callback response (method return) to Call <ResponseBody>. Let me know if it works properly.

Comment: I made some changes and now is falling correctly on "onResponse" method, check my answer on EDIT. But now I need to solve another problem when I send multiple files, only one was being uploaded to my server.